# Convert date variable to numeric

Tags: date, datetime, stata, variable-types

Feels like an obvious question, but Stata help hasn't yielded answers. Most Stata users are interested in converting a non-date variable into a date variable, but I want the opposite.

I have a date variable `date`, type long, format `%tdCCYYNN`. I'm trying to append it to a dataset in which the same variable `date` is type long and format `%12.0g`. To accurately do this, I need to convert `date` in the first dataset from `%tdCCYYNN` to `%12.0g`. When I do `format %12.0g date`, `date` values change to incorrect ones.

Let's say, in the first dataset, I have `date=201204`. I still want it to read `201204`, just as a `%12.0g` variable. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You have the problem backwards. If you have numbers in the second dataset that look like 201607 but are formatted %12.0g, then they are not Stata date values and cannot be used as such. You need to convert those values to Stata date values like the ones in the dataset you are appending.

Comment: If you have not already done so, it would benefit you to work your way through the guidance in` help datetime`, which is without a doubt the most visited documentation on my system, with the second-most-visited being Chapter 24 (Working with dates and times) of the *Stata User's Guide* PDF available from the PDF Documentation item on Stata's Help menu. Before working with dates and times, any Stata user should read the very detailed Chapter 24 thoroughly. After that, the help documentation will usually be enough to point the way.

Comment: Changing the display format does **not** change the value at all. Discussion at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0067 A more fundamental problem is that a value like 201204 cannot be a daily date. See http://www.statalist.org/forums/help#stata which gives hints on showing data examples to make your problem clear.

Comment: A daily date between 1 April 2014 and 30 April 2014 will display as 201204 when displayed with the format `%tdCCYYNN` shown in the initial post. Again, this all boils down to the user's unfamiliarity with how Stata stores dates in SIF and displays dates in HRF, and not understanding that a six-digit number that looks like a date is not usually usable as one in Stata. It is likely that the user will need to convert the SIF daily dates in the first dataset to SIF monthly dates, as well as (as recommended before) convert the numbers in the second dataset to SIF monthly dates.

Comment: Thank you both for the thoughtful responses. I intended to work with numeric values (not dates) because my legacy code treats the 'date' variable as a six digit number and performs integer operations on it. After struggling with converting to numeric (and before reading Richard's answer), I ended up converting the numeric variable to a date and changing the legacy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I +1 all the comments above by Nick and William and suggest you read `help datetime`. I have been using Stata for a few years and still frequently visit this help file. **Stata's date/time functionality is fantastic and you will benefit from learning it earlier rather than later.**

**I would convert the other data to Stata date format**. **Really**. But if you need to convert your `%td` date to an "integer YYYYNN" date, then pass through a temporary file. If you write your `%td` date to plain text, then it will keep the displayed format and you can read it back as an integer YYYYNN date.

```
// data that matches your decsription
clear
set obs 1
generate date = date("20120401", "YMD")
format date %tdCCYYNN
list

// write to tempfile as plain text
tempfile plainText
outsheet using "`plainText'"

// read back with dates as integers
preserve
tempfile StataData
insheet using "`plainText'", clear
rename date dateInteger
save "`StataData'"
restore

// merge to original data
merge 1:1 _n using "`StataData'"
list
describe
```

This yields the following.

```
. list

     +---------------------------------+
     |   date   dateIn~r        _merge |
     |---------------------------------|
  1. | 201204     201204   matched (3) |
     +---------------------------------+

. describe

Contains data
  obs:             1                          
 vars:             3                          
 size:             7                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              storage   display    value
variable name   type    format     label      variable label
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
date            int     %tdCCYYNN             
dateInteger     long    %12.0g                
_merge          byte    %23.0g     _merge     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorted by: 
     Note: Dataset has changed since last saved.
```

But I suggest you take advantage of Stata's date/time functionality.

Comment: This is helpful, but I trust that you are not endorsing the use of `%tdCCYYNN` as a format for a daily date. Without a specific reason, it just seems perverse to use a date format that suppresses information. As the OP appears to have abandoned this thread it is still not clear to me that there isn't confusion with monthly dates there somehow.

Comment: @NickCox -- Not at all! I will add a stronger disclaimer. :) Some suites don't have good date/time support so users end up using YYYYMMDD dates or other hacks. Anshu should use Stata as intended and suggested by you and William. But in the meantime this should help her get it done. One common tool in my field requires YYYYMMDD integer dates, so I use this quite frequently.